# $f'(x)>f(f(x))$ implies $f(f(f(x)))\leq0$ for nonnegative $x$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-calculus

> If $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfies $f'(x)>f(f(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f(f(f(x)))\leq0$ for all $x\geq0$.

I have some trouble to prove this. I wonder if there's some relations between this problem and the ODE $ f'(x)=f(f(x)) $. Could anybody provide a solution or some hints on this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a reference or proof of the statement in your first sentence? Also, $f'(x)=f(f(x))$ is not an ODE.

Comment: Yet one can see $y=f$ as a solution of the ode $y'(t)=f(y(t))$

Comment: @PietroMajer: only once $f$ is known, though ;)

Comment: It is a problem from a certain old contest. I do not know what is MO politics for such questions. If it is ok, I may post a reference.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : I am not sure either what the policies in such cases are but would like to see a reference, and an answer too.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Yes, an unknown solution of an unknown equation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is Problem 4 of Day 1 of IMC 2012, proposed by Tomáš Bárta from Prague, see [here](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2012/IMC2012-day1-solutions.pdf)